# What are the acknowledged literary influences on "Star Wars"?

Tags: inspiration, star-wars

It's well known that Lucas had a ton of cultural influences on "Star Wars" - mostly cinematic (Kurosawa, etc..) but also literary (at the very least, Campbell).

There are many sources that list possible literary influences (including [a Wikipedia article](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars_sources_and_analogues)) but all of the ones I saw, merely rely on "element A is similar in Star Wars and XYZ, so it's an influence", without direct proof that the influence happened. What I'm interested in, are influences that are **acknowledged by the creators** (Lucas, Kazan, etc...), or people who were intimately involved with canon (Leeland Chee etc...).

What are the **acknowledged** literary influences on "Star Wars"?